# Sharepoint 2013 Site Content > New Webpart Page

Tags: 2013, development, web-part, sharepoint-foundation, site-template

Please take a look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583147(v=office.11).aspx

In that link it explains how to add custom templates into SharePoint for when you create a new web-part page (I have attached an image to show what I'm talking about)

[image: Add New Web Part].

I showed the link to my boss because he has the server-side permissions to actually complete this task. In my excitement in finding think link I didn't see that it was SharePoint 2013 :(. My boss still looked around the files and could not figure it out.

Where is the file location in which I can add custom templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do have a look at the following response http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms916835.aspx - but the rules apply for newest editions too. Paul Storck had another http://www.dontpapanic.com/blog/?p=58 or http://www.manageprojectsonsharepoint.com/blog/2011/03/14/creating-your-own-web-part-page-layout-template/ (best for your case)

I believe you are actually looking at creating a new Web-Part page template which is totally different in behavior than an actual Publishing site (in which case answer given by Eric P. would apply).

Therefore, in your situation you need to look at how to deploy a new Web-Part page template by deployment via a Module within a Feature

Comment: "Therefore, in your situation you need to look at how to deploy a new Web-Part page template by deployment via a Module within a Feature"

Module within a Feature...I'm sorry but I don't follow. I will still read the link and guestimate when it comes to the location of files (because it is based off the 2003 version) and post back

Comment: The feature is a vessel to deploy artifacts, e.g. Modules (which allow deploying files in special locations in SharePoint). the 3rd link provides a manual way (one-time deployment). If you are looking for reusable code - than use Features (in 14 hive). http://doitwithsharepoint.blogspot.ch/2011/08/create-web-part-pages-with-custom.html

Comment: Hmm...well going through the link. At the very top is says to copy the Custspcf.aspx file to Local_drive:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\60\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033. Now the closes I found was: Microsoft Shared>VSTO>10.0>1033

I don't think thats the path I should go simply because I don't see templates and anothering else. I do see the 1033 folder.

I have my folder settings set to: Show all hidden folders.

Answer (score 1):

Just like PirateEric said, you have Page Layouts in SharePoint 2013 which can be useful.. Please check the below links:

[How to: Create a page layout in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822368.aspx)
[Creating A Custom Page Layout In SharePoint 2013](http://blog.navantis.com/create-a-custom-page-layout-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Please make sure Page Layouts are only available when you have websites based on Publishing template or you turn on Publishing Infrastructure feature (site collection and site level).

For dropping Web Parts in a Page Layout, through SharePoint Designer you can add Web Part Zones in your Page Layout.. Following thread contains the example:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/44f4c722-0606-4711-bfd9-da0f200702be/how-to-add-left-right-and-middle-web-part-zone-in-publishing-page-layout?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

**UPDATE**

I found it for SharePoint 2010, not sure same applies on SharePoint 2013:
http://doitwithsharepoint.blogspot.com/2011/08/create-web-part-pages-with-custom.html

Comment: Thanks for the last link. Unfortunately when it came to the step to "publish", I threw my hands in the air because I don't have that ability/feature? I'll forward this to my boss just in case but thanks. However, I should say that I already have my templates ready and made. I even have gifs ready that show what templates does what. I just need to add it to sharepoint so it can be selected and used. I am trying to add more to the OOTB web part pages

Comment: Just as above, i believe we are not actually looking at Page Layouts and Publishing sites, bur rather at a typical Collaboration site and these are Web Part pages - the actual layouts for a Web part Page.

Comment: thats correct @C.Marius-MVP. You said it better than I did.

Comment: Please see the update

Comment: Thank you for the link, I am currently reading it over :D

Answer (score 0):

Page layouts go in the Master Page gallery in the site collection root. You don't need server side access to put a file there, it can be done through the UI.

If it needs to be available to all site collections, then it needs to be bundled into a feature and deployed on the server.

Comment: Eric - i believe what we see are only Web Part pages, not actually those coming from Publishing sites.

Comment: I'm not trying to add a master page template. I'm trying to add several web part pages that I have already made and is ready to be used.

Comment: Right, master pages and page layouts get added into the Master page and page layout gallery. Those are page layouts that define where web parts and publishing content lives. He is creating a web part page which are derived from a page layout that contain web part zones.

Comment: Eric, still not sure he has Publishing on (e.g. SitePages in the picture), but rather the actual files to deploy directly in the actual library.

Comment: Whether the publishing infrastructure is on or not, page layouts (for web part and publishing pages) are in that gallery and to include another, it needs to be added there either from the UI, SPD, or deployed as a feature.